# Alter Integer ID with a UUID in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have tables with integer ID , I want to migrate these tables to a new ones with UUID instead of integer ID, the problem is this ID is a foreign key in other table , any suggestions ?

Comment: On update cascade? Back up your db first!

Comment: What does this have to do with Java or Spring?